# Games freeze when playing

Tags: windows-10, freeze, gaming

When I play most games, they freeze and stop working.  I have tested this playing online, they only freeze visually.  My input still works, as I have had my friend verify that my character still moves.  I still have volume and sounds that seem to be working properly.  I have two monitors and everything works just as it is supposed to on the other monitor.  The games don't lag before freezing.  My computer and drivers are all up to date.  I have looked everywhere and asked around, but can't find a solution, or even people with a similar problem.  I reset my computer and that seemed to work for a while, but 2 weeks later the issue resufraced.

I can play games like Hearthstone without an issue, but something like Heroes of the Storm or Grim Dawn freeze up.  Prey freezes up along with MGSV: The Phantom Pain.  Again, to clarify, my computer does not freeze up, but it seems just the game visuals do.

Specs for my PC are:
Windows 10 Home version 1709
OS build: 15063.674
Processor: Intel i7-3770K CPU @ 3.50GHz
RAM: 16 GB
64-bit
GPU: GeForce GTX 770

Comment: Do you have the same freezes while playing offline-games? For me it sounds like an internet connection issue.

Comment: If everything is still working except the image on the screen is frozen, that sounds like a graphics driver issue or an over-heating GPU. Have you downloaded the latest nVidia GPU drivers? http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/126179/en-us

Comment: It happens during offline games as well.  GeForce says that my drivers are up to date. I don't have to restart my computer or anything, I can close the game and open it up again it will run fine for a bit.

Comment: Have you checked the physical card to see if there's a wire/cable that's preventing the fan from spinning?  There's also a chance that the PSU is not performing as expected, causing an under power condition that might cause this.  What's your PSU power rating, brand, and how old is it?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware issue with the GPU.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to be yours hardware issue with the graphics card. Or may be you are not downloaded the original game setup because of cracked version of game sometimes have a gtich in software.